# Oracle Hint: Return the the newly created rows in recordset

Tags: java, oracle11g

May I know if there is a HINT to return the most newly created data first?

Example this statement

```
Select * from table where rownum=>5000
```

sometimes the newly created rows are not in the result set and

```
Select * from table where rownum=>5000 order by creation_date
```

if order by creation_time or last_modified, it will take too long to return.

so may I know if there is a way to HINT ORACLE to at least ensure those newly inserted rows are in the result set?

it doesn't need to be in any order just the newly created rows will be in the result will do.

i have exhausted every way to use order by last_modified or creation_time.

Comment: And you don't have a column `creation_time` or `last_modified`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656476/mysql-order-by-insertion-order-no-sorting-columns

Comment: maybe `Select * from table order by rownum desc` ?

Comment: I do have but it takes too long to process.

Comment: @seesee takes too long? is your date field not indexed? when you tested with date, can you paste that query in your question? i'd exxpect you did `select * from table where your_date >= to_date('date you last fetched the set, 'format') order by your_date`? or are you interested in a top-n style query based on date (newest first?)

Answer (score 0):

First, index the date column.

Second, specify an order by in descending order, so the newest dates appear first.

Third, use the first rows hint, as you actually just want the first rows quickly, though if you really want 5000 records, it is hardly just the first rows any more. You can pass a desired number of rows with the first rows hint, which allows oracle to pick the best approach for whatever volume of data you require.

Fourth, ensure you have up to date statistics for the table and index.