# Set Order Of column by Sequence sql

Tags: sql, rank

If I have a table like this:

```
Id Rnk
1   1
1   1 
1   2
1   2
```

and I want to arrange the table like that:

```
Id Rnk
1   1
1   2
1   1
1   2
```

And I want it to be fixed so when ever I'll select the table the order will be like this. Any Help on how can I do it?

Comment: There is no default order of a table. You ALWAYS need to define an `order by` to get a garanteed result

Answer (score 0):

> And I want it to be fixed so when ever I'll select the table the order
>   will be like this.

**Quick answer: it cannot be done.** You have to always use `ORDER BY` clause in the query if you want to get rows in desired order.

---

A few related questions and answers on this topis:

- [What is the default order of records for a SELECT statement in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql)

  [Default row ordering for select query in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899514/default-row-ordering-for-select-query-in-oracle)

  [SQL: What is the default Order By of queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries/8746712)

  [MySQL, ORDER BY insertion order, no sorting columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656476/mysql-order-by-insertion-order-no-sorting-columns)

---

**Quote from the Wikipedia: [Order by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by)**

> `ORDER BY` is the only way to sort the rows in the result set. Without
>   this clause, the relational database system may return the rows in any
>   order. If an ordering is required, the `ORDER BY` must be provided in
>   the `SELECT` statement sent by the application.

---

**Another quote from the Wikipedia**: [Relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database)

> The relational model specifies that **the tuples of a relation have no
>   specific order** and that the tuples, in turn, impose no order on the
>   attributes.

---

In order to get this concrete order you can use `row_number` analytic functions in this way:

```
SELECT "Id", "Rnk"
FROM ( 
  SELECT t.*,
         row_number() over (partition by "Id", "Rnk" order by "Id", "Rnk") as rn
  FROM Table1 t
) x
ORDER BY "Id", rn
```

A demo for PostgreSQL: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0b86522f37e927a86701e778006e8cad

`row_number` is now supported by most databases, even MySql will have this feature in the upcoming version